# Reading a matrix from a text file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, text

I'm trying to read a matrix from a given text file, put it in a dictionary and manipulate it later, however when I try to access the elements, "," shows as an element and it's really messing up my indexing

I've tried to use the split function and it seems to be reading it nicely, but ',' still appears as an element

```
def loadboard():
    f = open("game.txt", "r")
    A=f.readline()
    B=f.readline()
    C=f.readline()
    board=[]
    board = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f]
    print(board)
    game = {
            "player1" : A,
            "player2" :B,
            "who" : C,
            "board" : board
            }  
    f.close()
    return(game)
```

this is my text file

```
A
B
C
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0
0,0,1,2,2,2,0,0
0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

this is what I see when i print the board

```
Out[242]: 
['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n',
 '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 \n',
 '0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0 \n',
 '0,0,1,2,2,2,0,0\n',
 '0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0 \n',
 '0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0\n',
 '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n',
 '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0']
```

when i try to access the second element which should be a zero again, i get ','

```
board[0][1]
Out[243]: ','
```

Comment: EDIT: Fixed, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

This work well for me:

```
    board = []
    with open('toto.txt', 'r') as f:
        for row in f.read().strip().split("\n")[3:]:
            board.append(row.split(","))
    for line in board:
        print (line)
    print "board[0] : " + str(board[0])
    print "board[0][1] : " + str(board[0][1])
```

Output:

```
(venv) C:\Users\hlupo\Documents\SoTest>python test.py
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
board[0] : ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
board[0][1] : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('game.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f]
print(l)
```

Comment: hey, the problem is that my text file already has 3 lines above the matrix, which i read beforehand, so I don't think I could use your method. I'll update the code so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
matrix = []
with open('game.txt','r') as f:
    for row in f.read().strip().split("\n")[3:]:
        matrix.append(row.split(","))

print(matrix)
```